# Date validation Unknown modifier error

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using this string to validate a date field in dd/mm/yyyy' and 'dd-mm-yyyy format:

```
'/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\.- ](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[\/\.- ](19|20)\d{2}$/'
```

but I get this error

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '\' in /var/www/...fields_lib.php on line 102

Keep in mind the the above string is entered on a web application optional validation form field without any delimeter, because I think the form embed the delimeters itself.
For other validation types like, integer and decimal numbers, I had to remove the delimeters for the validation to work on this specific form.

Any ideas ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get that error; instead I get a "range out of order" error, for the reason @CanSpice gave.  To get the other error, I have to remove the first backslash in the character class (`[/\.- ]` instead of `[\/\.- ]`).  Then it interprets the `/` as a regex delimiter, and it expects the next character to be a modifier (like `i` for *case-insensitive*, or `m` for *multiline*).

So you've got two problems: the `-` being treated as a range operator, and the `/` being treated as a regex delimiter.  You can deal with both problems by escaping the offending characters with backslashes (i.e., `[\/.\- ]`), but each problem has a more elegant solution.  If you move the `-` to the first or last position where it couldn't form a range, it gets treated as a literal `-`.  As for the `/`, you can use something else for the regex delimiter.  For example:

```
'~^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/. -](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[/. -](19|20)\d{2}$~'
```

FYI, the `.` never needed to be escaped at all.  In character classes, most regex metacharacters lose their special meanings.  You just happened to run afoul of two special cases. :-/

Comment: With the string you have posted, it's working now and it's validating the field.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the backslashes in character classes, so your regex should read (in part) `[/. -]`. Also note that the space and the dash have switched spaces, because `[.- ]` would be interpreted as "any character between `.` and .